# EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 1, address=0x1) when preforming segue

Tags: swift

When preforming a manual segue with performSegueWithIdetifier it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 1, address=0x1). I have 3 ViewControllers in my game(Using only UiKit, Not SpriteKit), lets say VC1, VC2, and VC3. I am able to successfully go from the VC1 to VC2 controller. The VC2 is has the majority of the code and UIObjects for my game. The problem is I am not able to get from VC2 to VC3. It always throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 1, address=0x1). I've spent a ton of time on this program and have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: What does the error output say? My guess is that there's an error when accessing an outlet that was never hooked up in your VC3.

Comment: The code that throws the error is: performSegueWithIdentifier("toEndScreen", sender: nil ),                                                               Here is an image of the error http://imgur.com/mdcfwqw   @NRitH

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out, I was missing some code. This fixed the issue for me:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "tableToRec") {
        let DestViewContoller : RecorderViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! RecorderViewController
        if savedURL != nil {
            DestViewContoller.savedURL = savedURL!
        }
    }

    if (segue.identifier == "tableToPreset") {
        let DestViewContoller : PresetViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PresetViewController
        if savedURL != nil {
            DestViewContoller.savedURL = savedURL!
        }
    }

}
```